# Web.config setup for IIS development

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am running an IIS instance (Not the default IIS Express) on which I have configured my ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project.
I would like to configure my web.config file, so that I have the following behavior:

1. Each time i update a view (.cshtml file) in my solution, the update is instantly visible after  i refresh the page.
2. Each time i update a controller or a model (.cs file) the update becomes visible after a rebuild of the solution.

What I currently have is the following configuration in my root directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Live.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Now with the following configuration I have to rebuild each time I want to see the result of my modifications. There's also another problem, each time I rebuild the app I encounter the following problem:

```
1>D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4502,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Live.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Live.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Live.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have to manually stop the IIS instance and then rebuild my solution.

I have worked on a project where this was the way things were done, however I never figured out how it was configured. I would appreciate any help if possible, Thanks.

Comment: For .NET Core 3.1 you are out of luck. Migrate to .NET 6 and you can start to use hot reload, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Comment: Odd, this is working for me on .NET Core 3.1... If I want to modify my views I just edit them and refresh the page in my browser (Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation). If I want to modify controller logic, I just make my modifications and then hit the red button. I think I'll stick to this way. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Hello samwu, thank you for getting in touch with me. I have choosen the default way of developing my app. However, I cannot foresee if in the future I would need to configure my app in the way I described. If that's okay, I could leave an URL to my github repository here. Keep in mind however that I have removed the web.config file in favour of the json configuration.